# Google Script - importing file data from a file name listed in a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Very new to this, but have been pretty lucky with my tinkering in the past. Really stuck on this one, however.

Looking to import file data to specific sheets. With a specific file name, I've been successful with this script:

```
  function importVauto() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var import1 = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Import1');

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("samplefilename").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  import1.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  }
```

The challenge is, the file names change weekly. My thought was to have the required file names listed in a spreadsheet, reference the cell containing the file name, and import the required file. Tried this:

```
function importVauto() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var import1 = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Import1');
  var data = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');

  var name = data.getRange("C24")
  name.getValues()
  Logger.log(name)

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name).next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  import1.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

Appears there is a problem with using the var 'name' as the file name for DriveApp.getFilesByName(), but chances are, there's a ton I'm missing (don't know what you don't know).

Hopefully this question makes sense (and even more hopefully, there is a simple solution). Again, very new to this. Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- `getValues()` returns 2 dimensional array. If you want to retrieve the value of one cell "C24", you can use `getValue()`. In this case, you can directly retrieve the string value of the cell.

#### Modified script :

From :

```
name.getValues();
```

To :

```
name = name.getValue();
```

OR

```
name = name.getValues()[0][0];
```

#### Note :

- When you retrieve `file` using `DriveApp.getFilesByName(name).next()`; if there are several files with the same filename, this can retrieve only one of them. Please be careful about this.

#### References :

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you for modifying. I could study from it. I want to know about the way to do upvote to this.

Comment: name = name.getValue() did the trick!! Very much appreciate the help!